# magento 2 how to create static block that contains categories need to display in home page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I want to create an static block that contains categories and their products need to display in home page in magento2

Comment: you can follow [this](https://blog.landofcoder.com/display-products-of-specific-category-on-home-page/) way

Comment: Thanks for comments  Hit's article don't provide complete info

Comment: I think the URL which Hit's provided you explain what you have asked in your question. If not so then can you be more specific on your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your static block you need to pass data like this.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myblock" template="Vendor_Extension::test.phtml" mycats="1,2,3"}}
```

And now you can access this variable into your phtml file like this.

```
$myCat = $block->getData('mycats');
```

Or

```
$myCat = $block->getMycats();
```

Now phtml file, you can do what you like.